# is posible in wordpress post to replace a single word

Tags: wordpress

I have on idea but i dont know if that is posible eg. 
I'm writing a post in Wordpress site and I have to write a word too many times, is possible to write it once at the start and in the other part it to be written automatically by a shortcut or do I need a plugin. So if I change that word at the start all the other similar words to be changed automatically, like in word document action find and replace.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a [Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) for that. And you can write [your own mini-plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Standard_Plugin_Information) to do it.

The plugin would be simply:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Single Word Shortcode 
 */

add_shortcode( 'so', 'shortcode_so_22482571' );

function shortcode_so_22482571( $atts )
{
    return "<a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Stack Overflow</a>";
}
```

After activation, all `[so]` occurrences in your posts and pages will be converted to the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) link.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a shortcode, like brasoflio said, or you could just do exactly what you were thinking about in Word.... just do a find and replace in your document. Write the document in a text or markdown editor. Replace all instances of {abcdefg} with whatever text you want. Alternatively, you could use a find and replace plugin, or even write your own shortcode. But for something like this, I'd err on the side of laziness. Just write your text in a text editor, find and replace, then copy it in